# Looking for a way to generate Java and C# classes from common source code

Tags: java, c#, code-generation

I have a library of 'operators' coded in C#.

Each operator implements the same interface, and is able to process an array of primitives (int, double, string, int[], double[], string[]) then returns a primitive. The code inside operators is made of basic language features like basic mathematics operations, string operations, loops, if.

Now, I want to be able to run this logic both in java and C# and I neither want to use JNI wrapper, nor use Mono.

I am looking for a way to generate java classes and C# ones from one single code source / configuration.
One obvious solution is to define my own grammar, then code a parser and classes generator, but I am wondering if there exists any know language-neutral, platform-neutral mechanisme to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I can imagine is to use a transpiler such as http://www.cs2j.com/. It depends a lot in what you are working with. For example, if you are developing an API, you could use an api framework like Swagger, using YAML or JSON (and the code editor itself has the option to transform to different client/server languages).